# MRTG -- Setting Date for Old Data

Tags: ubuntu, mrtg

I have installed MRTG on ubuntu server to monitor network infra. In that I am only getting present day data.

I want to know old data also, how can I get the old data. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Have you previously been collecting data? If not, there's no way to retroactively get old performance data.

Comment: How can I collect previous data? Can you please let me know.

Comment: You cannot. As I said, unless you've been collecting this data, there is no way to retroactively retrieve it.

Comment: No No, What I meant to ask you is, From now how can I get it?

Comment: As you always do with MRTG, you configure SNMPd on your devices, and configure MTRG to collect whatever data you want.